# Draw a horizontal 1 line box with unicode characters

Tags: unicode

I would like to draw a horizontal box (box and whiskers plot) with Unicode characters. Something like this:

```
|------------[===+====]-----------------|
```

...but nicer. The goal is to produce a box and whisker plot on one line only.

I found the box drawing characters `\U+2500` (─), `\U+251C` and `\U+2524` (├ and ┤, respectively), so the whiskers can be done:

```
├────────────[===+====]─────────────────┤
```

...but what about the middle part? I can't seem to figure out how to do it nicely. The box drawing characters can be used to draw a box which takes more than one line, but not for a box (or rectangle) that fits on one line only. By "nice" I mean something that looks more like a rectangle than "[======]".

[Here](https://www.simplypsychology.org/boxplots.html) is a good explanation what a box and whisker plot is.

P.S. Here is my current solution, demonstrated using the famous Iris data set of Fisher. I am not 100% happy with it, so still looking for a better combination of Unicode characters:

```
   Col                     Summary                                                                                                                  
 1 Petal.Length.setosa                   ╾─────▇▇◆▇────╼                                                                                            
 2 Petal.Length.versicolor                                              ╾──────────────▇▇▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇───────╼                                           
 3 Petal.Length.virginica                                                                      ╾────────▇▇▇▇▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇▇───────────────╼               
 4 Petal.Width.setosa      ╾─◆▇────╼                                                                                                                
 5 Petal.Width.versicolor                ╾──▇◆▇▇▇▇───╼                                                                                              
 6 Petal.Width.virginica                       ╾─────▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇▇──╼                                                                                   
 7 Sepal.Length.setosa                                                                      ╾──────▇▇▇◆▇▇▇─────────╼                                
 8 Sepal.Length.versicolor                                                                           ╾──────────▇▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇▇▇──────────╼              
 9 Sepal.Length.virginica                                                                            ╾───────────────────▇▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇▇▇▇──────────────╼
10 Sepal.Width.setosa                                        ╾─────────────▇▇▇◆▇▇▇▇──────────╼                                                      
11 Sepal.Width.versicolor                               ╾───────▇▇▇▇▇◆▇▇▇─────╼                                                                     
12 Sepal.Width.virginica                                   ╾─────────▇▇▇◆▇▇─────────╼
```

Comment: Define *exactly* what you mean by “do it nicely”. Precisely what shapes are you shopping for?

Comment: It looks like *all* of the characters in the box drawing classification are meant to draw through the middle of the character box, not along the edges.  You may have no choice but to use two lines.

Comment: If you don't mind your box being filled in, you could use the block characters `U+2588 █`, `U+2591 ░`, `U+2592 ▒`, or `U+2593 ▓`.

Comment: Yes, I tried them, but it does not look well: the problem is that 2588 takes a full line, so if the box plots are one under another they join; and 2587 and other shorter variants are no symmetric around middle. Unfortunately using two lines is not an option For Reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite clear on exactly what shapes you need. Here are some possibilities.

## Box-drawing character

Perhaps the [box-drawing characters found in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character#Unicode) suit your needs.

## Block elements

See [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) listing lines in various widths, both horizontal and vertical.

## Geometric shapes

See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) for characters in various shapes of squares, circles, and triangles. See [Unicode specification](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf).

## Symbols for Legacy Computing

You might also be interested in the [*Symbols for Legacy Computing*](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1FB00.pdf) added to Unicode 13. [Discussed on sibling site](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14099/851). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_for_Legacy_Computing).

## Apps

If not quite what you need, look around. There are around 140,000 characters in Unicode now. There are many apps and web sites dedicated to the encyclopedia of Unicode characters. On macOS, I recommend *Unicode Checker*.

Try the [ShapeCatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/) web site that interactively matches your finger-drawing to a subset of various Unicode characters.

Comment: Box drawing characters unfortunately are not suitable to draw a box on one line only. I will rephrase my question.

Comment: P.S. Regarding your comment "search to learn more", I don't have "String" and "Character" classes in my programming language.

Comment: @January Whoops, I am usually looking at Java-related Questions.

Comment: Well, I have seen these already. I tried several options, but they all don't look good. I was kind of hoping that someone already struggled with the same problem and found a neater solution... But thanks in any case!